# Is there an easy way to Extract Interface in Visual Studio Express 2010 Edition?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-express, automated-refactoring

I have a large class from which I want to extract interface.

I only found "Extract Method" under Refactor Option, so I am wondering if there is any free tool available that does that, so I do not have to create the interface by hand?

Comment: Tha's non-trivial and I don't know if free apps exist.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736276/is-there-any-safe-refactoring-tool-for-net-or-at-least-c

Comment: Steve, VS Express doesn't allow you to install extensions / add-ins.
To answer the TS, if it isn't available in any menu, it isn't available. (They have to limit the Express edition enough in order to sell the professional and higher editions :P.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question for other users with the same problem.

After looking around the web I came across [SharpDevelop](http://sharpdevelop.codeplex.com/) which is The Open Source IDE for .NET and it has some features that are missing in Visual Studio Express.

One of those features is also Extract Interface.

Answer (score 1):

I do it through Resharper, but it can be done natively in VS through Class Designer.  From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek50xay4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> To extract members to a new interface
>
> In Class Designer, right-click the type that contains the member or members you want to extract, point to Refactor, and click Extract
>   Interface.
>
> The Extract Interface dialog box displays default values for the name of the interface and the name of the code file in which it will
>   be declared. Either accept the default values or change them.
>
> In the Select public members to form interface pane, select or clear the check box next to the members you want to extract into the
>   new interface, and click OK.
>
> A new interface is created, and the file that houses it is added to the project.

Comment: Apparently the class designer also doesn't exist in the Express editions.